# How to split a JSON lookalike string and display it on vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, web, vue.js

I have a string of the form:

```
"{ "name" : "XYZ", "email" : "XYZ@ABC.com" }  { "name" : "PQR", "email" : "PQR@ABC.com" } "
```

How do I split this string/parse it and ID it in a proper way to display just the names and the emails on the client side?

Expect something like this ---

```
XYZ
XYZ@ABC.com

PQR
PQR@ABC.com
```

Comment: Can you share more of the code you've tried so far? Show us some methods, etc that you're working with.

Comment: If you have a `JSON` string as input, you may consider to use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) first and then get the data you need from its result.

Comment: the string you provided have some additional brackets before the second object, if this is of the proper json string formate JSON.parse will work here

Comment: It is not a JSON string, just looks very similar to it. I could not use JSON.parse() on it

Comment: share the actual string then?

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position" is the error I am getting while trying to use JSON.parse

Comment: I guess you'll have to use indexOf('name') and indexOf('email') to find the following name and email. Remove the first part {} of the string and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this string coming from? It looks like a set of JSON objects concatenated together? To munge it into a JSON string you can do the below. But this is ugly, better to fix the source of the string so its proper JSON.

```js
let string = '{ "name" : "XYZ", "email" : "XYZ@ABC.com" } { "name" : "PQR", "email" : "PQR@ABC.com" } ';
string = string.replace(/}\s*{/,"},{");
console.log(JSON.parse(`[${string}]`));
```